# I am trying to figure out what this python program does running it by hand

Tags: python

```
def dumb_multiply(a, b):
    """Multiply positive integers a and b."""
    p = 0
    while b!=0:
        p,b = p+a, b-1
    return p
```

I am trying to run this by hand but i keep getting confused on this line "p,b = p+a, b-1" is it setting p=p+a and b=b-1?. I can't figure out how the program gets the solutions

Comment: Regarding your question, why not try it out and see what happens?

Comment: Please use Markdown formatting, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It multiplies two positive integers by doing a+a+...+a (b times)

```
Let a=4, b=3
Start:
p=0
b!=0 True
p = 0+4, b=3-1
b!=0 True
p = 4+4, b=2-1
b!=0 True
p = 8+4, b=1-1
b!=0 False
Return 12
```

Comment: this makes sense, but when i run it on the computer i get the value of a back

Comment: wow so i fixed the indentation on my return to align with the while and it gave me the correct answer. thank you. i did not know python was sensitive to indentations

Comment: would i be able to write this program as a for loop? if so how would it change

Comment: Yeah, **indentations** are the foundation of python. That's how it knows when a scope is ended.

Comment: for i in range(b): *indentation* p = p + a